Retrieve original Tex command
I have access to an old private website, as a client.
The original TeX command is not present anywhere in the page_source nor the rendered document. However, it is clearly somewhere in memory, because I can right click on the math expression, select "Show Math as TeX command", and see the original TeX command.
How can I retrieve the original command in javascript, from the browser console?
I tried to do:
window.MathJax.startup.document.getMathItemsWithin(document.body);

and then access the math element, but this shows me the MathML code (which happens to be Math input error, and not the original TeX command (the malformed \( € 0.7 (\ ).

You have the right approach, and the command you have given will return an array of internal structures that contain not just the original TeX, but other data as well.  To get the TeX portion, use
const list = MathJax.startup.document.getMathItemsWithin(document.body);
for (const item of list) {
  console.log(item.math);
}

That should get you all the TeX in the page.

EDIT:  Here is an example you can run to see that it works.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>MathJax Test</title>
<script>
MathJax = {
  startup: {
    pageReady() {
      return MathJax.startup.defaultPageReady().then(() => {
        const list = MathJax.startup.document.getMathItemsWithin(document.body);
        for (const item of list) {
          alert(item.math);
        }
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" defer="" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>The price: \( €0.7 \)</p>
</body>
</html>




Thanks for your answer Davide. Unfortunately, it does not quite work. item.math returns the mathML element, which says in this case "Math input error". The original TeX was "( € 0.7 ("  The euro sign is causing this error, and I'd like to get to the original TeX. I know it's possible because I can right click on it and get it, but I'd like to do it programmatically.

No, getMathItemsWIthin() gets you a MathJax MathItem object, which has a math property that is the original TeX.  As the author of MathJax, I know that that is the case, and i tested the code before posting.  It is true that the MathItem also includes a typesetRoot property that points to the DOM elements that include the Math input error message, and a root property that is MathJax's internal format (which is based on MathML).  Did you actually try the code?

I've added a working example to my post.

Hi Davide, thank you for your further answer. I did try the code, yes, but unfortunately it still does not work for my case.
It does work when there is no math error.
But for the badly form case, I see this:
Math input error
and not the original tex. There must be something strange the website is doing.

It is possible that the site is pre-processing the on the server and inserting the MathML into the page rather than the TeX.  The only way that item.math would be MathML is if the page already had MathML in it.  But that would usually mean that the MathJax contextual menu is no present, so if it is, that seems unlikely.  Can you give a link to the page in question, so I can take a look?

PS, I assume that the example I added to my answer above shows the TeX not MathML for you, right?

unfortunately I am not able to share the website, as it's a private resource.

Correct, your example shows the TeX.

Well, I'm sorry to say, then, that I don't have any other suggestions.  There is something more complicated going on with that website, and without access to it, or more information about the processes it is performing, there is not much we can do to help.

That's fair, I understand. I'll mark your answer as correct, as it's the best possible answer in the circumstances.
